# WP8 Play sound when application is onbackground

Tags: windows-phone-8

Developing tools : Visual Studio 2012, target wp platform : wp8.

I am facing the above problem:

**When my application is running on background  and i am receiving a notification i vibrate the phone successful and i want to play a specific sound.**

What i have tried so far:

```
   Player = new MediaElement();

                    Player.AutoPlay = true;
                    Player.Volume = 5;
                    Player.Source = new Uri("/data/alert.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Player.MediaOpened += (Object s, RoutedEventArgs args) =>
                    {
                        Player.Play();
                    };
```

I i am not getting any exception but no sound. Neither on foreground nor background .
Am i missing something?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `MediaElement` API to play notification sounds when the app is in background. In order to launch a notification and play a custom sound, you need to use the `ShellToast` and use the `Sound` property via reflection.

Here is how play a custom notification sound from background (MSDN link) [Using custom sounds in toasts on Windows Phone 8 Update 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_gdr3)

EDIT: When the app is running in foreground, you can use the same technique (ShellToast with Sound).

Comment: Interesting... i will try it. As for foreground ?

Comment: Thx a lot +1 for your try, i thing that is the solution o need :)

Comment: Something irrelevant with this post. Do you know if a can use something like messagebox when the app is on background in order to get "dialog result"? Toast as far as i know is not a dialog in order to have buttons and get the use feed back.

Comment: This is not possible. The only way to interact with the user when the app is in background is using the Toast API (or Live Tiles, but that won't help in your case).

Comment: Thx a lot. I knew it but not for sure. So i will have NavigationUri in the toast in order to get the user interaction there. Thx a lot again :)

Answer (score 1):

Even `MediaPlayer` class can help you play  songs and media in the background when you are showing a toast or a small pop up dialog.

Check here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.play.aspx

Comment: Can play sound when the whole app runs in the background ?

Comment: Yes it does play.
I have played an audio in a similar case that you have described above. I have used MediaPlayer and it does work well. You need to have the song to be played at hand. Thats it.